# Problem with DateTimeContinuousAxis, one day is added to each date without no apparent reason [Nativescript-Angular]

Tags: angular, mobile, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I receive a json like this from `chartService`, But when I try to show the data, 1 day is added to each date. I am using Genymotion for emulate. I don't know if it could be an internal emulator time zone problem, will anyone know what is happening?

```
JSON = [{
"fecha": "2019-09-23",
"km_rec": 431.56
}, {
"fecha": "2019-09-25",
"km_rec": 187.12
}, {
"fecha": "2019-09-26",
"km_rec": 270.08
}, {
"fecha": "2019-09-27",
"km_rec": 121.04
}, {
"fecha": "2019-09-28",
"km_rec": 407.96
}, {
"fecha": "2019-09-29",
"km_rec": 10.98
}]
```

```html
<StackLayout class="c-stacklayout" alignItems="flex-end">
    <GridLayout class="modal_chart">
        <RadCartesianChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>            
            <DateTimeCategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis dateFormat="dd-MMM" labelFitMode="Rotate" labelRotationAngle="-1.2" labelTextColor="black"></DateTimeCategoricalAxis>
            <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis allowPan="false" allowZoom="false"></LinearAxis>
            <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries selectionMode="DataPointMultiple" showLabels="true" [items]="distance" valueProperty="km_rec" categoryProperty="fecha">
                <PointLabelStyle tkLineLabelStyle fontStyle="Bold" fillColor="#FC6060" textSize="12" textColor="White">
                </PointLabelStyle>
            </LineSeries>
            <RadCartesianChartGrid tkCartesianGrid horizontalLinesVisible="true" verticalLinesVisible="false" verticalStripLinesVisible="false" horizontalStripLinesVisible="true" >
            </RadCartesianChartGrid>
        </RadCartesianChart>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.initDataItems()
}

  private initDataItems() {
   this.checkedDistanceData();
}

checkedDistanceData() {
    this.query(Config.storage.vehicleSelected, veh => {
        this.query(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + this.id_veh, data => {
          if (data) {
            this.setChartDistance(JSON.parse(data.value));
                ...
                } else {
                   this.chartService();
                   ...
                }
            });
        };
    });

  chartService() {
    this.httpGet(route (www.dis....),
      data => {
        this.setChartDistance(data);
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    },
      error => {
          error...
    }, null);
}
  get getchartDistance() {
      return distance;
}

  setChartDistance(chart) {
    this.distance = chart;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should [store your dates in milliseconds](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/Chart/Axes/datetimecontinuous#data-binding-specifics).

Most likely you're passing a date object that is getting serialized and on deserialization it's losing/gaining some hours and flipping to the next day.

You might want to run some tests if using `UTC` or the local timezone is better for this (since you're using moment you can use `moment.utc()` and then get it in ms).

See the example here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/master/chart/app/examples/data-models/date-time-model.ts

Comment: I finished using `CategoricalAxis` and [moment library](https://momentjs.com/docs/). I saw that I lost the time zone if I tried to pass it that way, but thnks anyway.